# ArcGIS ADF - how to click and bring up a popup with informations on the feature selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have an asp.net ADF application with a map, I need to bring up a small tooltip window or a popup window with feature information when a user clicks on one

I need to retrieve all features in all layers under the clicked point and display their information. I know I can do this with the "identify" function. But how to display a tooltip window with ADFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with arcgis' standard tips